# highlight.js doesn't auto detect language

Tags: javascript, web, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I downloaded `highlight.pack.js` from https://highlightjs.org/download/ and expecting it to highlight `<pre><code>` block automatically, without specifying any languages.

However an exeption is thrown when I load the page:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /([Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(<[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*(\s*,\s*[Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$][Ã€-Ê¸a-zA-Z_$0-9]*)*>)?\s+)+[a-zA-Z_]\w*\s*\(/: Range out of order in character class
```

But if I specify the language `<pre><code class="fsharp">` then everything works fine. Also, the cdn hosted `highlight.min.js` can auto-detect languages but it doesn't have the languages I need.

Any idea how I can get it work?

Comment: Can you try including `charset="utf-8"` to the `<script>` tag where you're including the `highlight.js` library?

Comment: @DavidR Genius! It works :)

Comment: Glad that it worked, Can you please accept my answer (given below) then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be including `charset="utf-8"` to the  tag where you're including the `highlight.js` library.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add UTF-8 characterset in the head section of your HTML file :

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```